# Функция strip_tags удаляет текст треугольных скобках, не только теги. Как этого избежать?

Tags: php, html

Использую `strip_tags` чтобы в некоторых местах сайта убирать `<html>` тэги из оформления текста.

Но он вырезает обычный текст в `<>` скобках.

Вопрос: можно-ли как-то экранировать эти скобки, чтобы `strip_tags` не удалял их или возможно есть какое-то другое свойство, которое скроет html теги из текста и не применит html теги к оформлению текста.

Возможно как-то через `str_replace`

Например:

```
Пользователь вводит:
<h1 style="color:red;">Классный туториал</h1><br>по основам <!html>

На одну страницу, должно вывестись следующее:
Классный туториал
по основам <!html>
(с оформлением HTML соотвественно)

А на другой странице вот так:
Классный туториал по основам <!html>

Без HTML оформления и без вывода html тэгов в строк, но текст в скобках должен остаться.
```

Comment: Попробуйте в strip_tags() передавать вторым параметром тот текст в скобках, который не надо удалять.

Comment: Как его передать, как его взять из скобок?

Comment: Я с телефона, пример не могу сейчас написать. Почитайте описание strip_tags() на php.net, там есть наглядные примеры.

Comment: вы не находите несколько странным, что в вашей html разметке присутствует какой-то текст в угловых скобках помимо тегов?

Comment: @teran Ну, пользователь может всякое

Comment: пользователь то может и может. но задача разработчика экранировать шляпу всякую при выводе.

Comment: единственный вариант когда вы не экранируете на сайте пользовательский текст, это когда пользователь пользуется некоторым wysiwyg редактором, формируя разметку самостоятельно. Если это ваш случай, то для начала изучите возможности редактора, по возможностям настройки используемых тегов. Ибо все таки, редактор используется для ввода не всей страницы, а только некого контента. Поэтому функции фильтрации тегов а-ля `<html>` вполне себе логичный функционал.

Comment: Если нет такого, то выберите все возможные теги в документе. Сравнете их с вашим белым списком, и остальное обрежьте теми же самыми `strip_tags`. Если все же у вас никого редактора нет, то просто экранируйте ваш вывод. Если в ваших  намерениях нет ввода html, то не надо из-за этого кромсать пользовательский ввод, преобразуйте все что требуется в html сущности, и показывайте как есть.

Comment: @teran Случай такой. Вот есть строка с html тэгами и текстом в скобках. На одной странице, html тэги должны применяться, а на другой странице эти html теги не должны применяться, но тогда они пишутся как текст, что тоже неправильно. Мне нужна та же строка, только без тэгов и без html оформления, но стрип вырезает и тэши и текст в таких скобках

Comment: давайте еще пример строки такой приведите в вопросе, чтобы с конкретикой

Comment: @teran Дополнил

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы `strip_tags` не удалял текст в угловых скобках, они должны быть проэкранированы в исходном тексте. Для этого `<` нужно заменить на `&lt;`, а `>` на `&gt;`.

Сделать такую замену за вас может [функция `htmlspecialchars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). Но она заменит все-все вхождения таких скобок, потому скобки нужно заменять в исходном тексте. Это не какая-то прихоть PHP, такого отношения требует сам HTML.

Comment: получается, просто через replace надо заменить скобки на их код и не применять к выводу htmlspecialchars?

Comment: `str_replace` вам тоже заменит *все* скобки на коды. Вам нужно добиться того, чтобы вы исходном тексте не было таких скобок с самого начала. Магии не существует.

Comment: Значит нужно при добавлении в бд заменить их на коды, но я спрашиваю, на выходе нужен htmlspecialchars или нет? Я не понял ваш вывод

Comment: Если вы храните в БД валидный HTML без сюрпризов, то не нужен. Иначе - нужен.

Comment: Так где заменять эти скобки на код? На входе или выходе?

Comment: Вариант с replace не подошёл, потому что заменяет все скобки, тегов в том числе

Comment: Заменять нужно на входе и заменять нужно руками, в общем случае.

Comment: Ну, а как определить, html тэг это текст в <> скобках? Это как раз и есть суть вопроса. То что скобки надо экранировать было с самого начала.